# Magic-FN like Binds For Normal Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, hotkeys

SO, I'm obsessed with my Anne Pro 2 (even though it really is not reliable) but I wanna know if there is another way to use its software (Obinskit) or something similar to it. Basically I want to hold my Caps-Lock that will give me a chance to use my j,k,l, and i key as arrow keys (that's how I currently have my Anne Pro 2 set-up). Is that any alternative software or is Obinskit just for that particular keyboard?

PS: it uses the Caps-Lock as a 'Magic-FN' key that completely changes the layout of your keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will use
the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key as a modifier to convert the i,j,k,m to arrow
keys, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Other modifier such as <kbd>Shift</kbd> will be passed on with the arrow.

```
SetNumLockState, AlwaysOff
SetStoreCapsLockMode, Off

Capslock & Space::Ctrl
Capslock & w::Shift

$*I::
if GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")
  send {blind}{up}
else
  send {blind}{i}
return

$*J::
if GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")
  send {blind}{left}
else
  send {blind}{j}
return

$*K::
if GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")
  send {blind}{right}
else
  send {blind}{k}
return

$*M::
if GetKeyState("Capslock", "P")
  send {blind}{down}
else
  send {blind}{m}
return
```

The above `GetKeyState` call will check the physical state of the
<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, not its logical state.

The commands `SetNumLockState` and `SetStoreCapsLockMode` are required
to disable the normal functioning of the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key,
so doing upper-case will require using <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [GetKeyState](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)
- [SetCapsLockState](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: Can you help me, I don't want the caps lock to turn on while I use it with the i,j,k,m keys. I also wanted to used the space bar as the Control key and w as the Shift key but it seems to get stuck and does not want to turn off.

HILFEEEEEE

Comment: I have modified the script.